# Apt-cacher-ng 403 forbidden on specific package

Tags: ubuntu, caching, rabbitmq, apt

Package: apt-cacher-ng
Version: 3.1-1

We've configured an apt proxy server with apt-cacher-ng, while it works for most packages, when trying to install rabbitmq-server with mentioning a specific version it fails with 403 error.
Any attempts to use regex in the V/PfilePatternEx ended up with the same result.

We are using ubuntu 18.04.2 on both server and client

on the client side it looks like this:

```
Err:1 http://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial/main amd64 rabbitmq-server all 3.6.15-1
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian/pool/rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server_3.6.15-1_all.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and in the /var/log/apt-cacher-ng/apt-cacher.log on the proxy server:

```
1554714729|I|436|apt-cacher-client|dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian/pool/rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server_3.6.16-1_all.deb [HTTP error, code: 403]

1554714729|E|1173|apt-cacher-client|dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian/pool/rabbitmq-server/rabbitmq-server_3.6.16-1_all.deb [HTTP error, code: 403]
```

Any bug-fix we tried had the same result.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Read this my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62226563/error-status-code-is-403-mongodbs-404-this-means-that-the-requested-version/69278562#69278562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me after changing the `UserAgent` in `/etc/apt-cacher-ng/acng.conf`.

```
UserAgent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.6.10)
```